# How to force a CSS class to be used from another file?

Tags: css

I think the title is a bit vague but my vocabulary is limited in english. I'll try to explain what I want to do.

I have two CSS files from products I have no control ( are not mine ). Lets say AdminLTE bootstrap and a [JQuery plugin](https://github.com/sebmatton/jQuery-Flight-Indicators).

The problem is the `Box` class is in both styles.

[image]

and messing my flight indicators from the JQuery plugin. I know I have to choose the order of CSS style files or add `important` to one of them but I'm afraid of start to mess with my bootstrap interface.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: I highly suggest that you NEVER EVER use ```important``` in a CSS file. It inevitably creates a mess of overrides and inheritance issues and has given me one too many headaches! The only time ```important``` should be used is when you are overriding styles that you don’t have access to (like adding custom styles to a SquareSpace or Weebly site).

Comment: @MorrisonBower thanks for the advice. I'll consider this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I have to choose the order of CSS style files or add important to one of them

you don't, you could simply write a selector with higher specificity which would override the jQuery plugin styles, like `body div.instrument .box`